# Where am I going wrong retrieving stock data from Quandl?

Tags: python, api, dataframe, stock, quandl

```
ValueError: The Quandl API key must be provided either through the api_key variable or through the environmental variable QUANDL_API_KEY.
```

I am trying to retrieve some simple stock data from Quandl. I have put in the actual API key instead of the x in the below example code below but I am still getting errors. Am I missing out on something?

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

symbol = 'AAPL'
api_key = 'x'

start = dt.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

df = web.DataReader(symbol, 'quandl', start, end, api_key)

print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [quandl docs](https://docs.quandl.com/docs/python-installation):

> AUTHENTICATION The Quandl Python module is free but you must have a
>   Quandl API key in order to download data. To get your own API key, you
>   will need to create a free Quandl account and set your API key.
>
> After importing the Quandl module, you can set your API key with the
>   following command: `quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "YOURAPIKEY"`

So you will need to pip install and `import quandl`. Then you can set the `api_key` attribute as above.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to get the data from Quandl, maybe you can try another approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl

api_key = 'yoursuperamazingquandlAPIkey'
df = Quandl.get('heregoesthequandlcode', authtoken = api_key)

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Further to Ishan's great answer, you can also set the api and then just call items from QUANDL...   import quandl
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = 'yoursuperamazingquandlAPIkey'  , then just quandl.get("quandlcode")